# A combinatorial gadget for smoothly slice knots

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

As far as I searched, I couldn't find something valuable but is there any combinatorial (or computable) gadget for knots to guarantee them to be smoothly slice?

For example, by the virtue of the great article of **Freedman**, topologically slice knots have such gadget in the following fashion:

**Theorem**([Fre82](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214437136)): If $K$ has Alexander polynomial $1$, then $K$ is topologically slice.

But the converse of the theorem is not true due to the work of **Hedden-Livingston-Ruberman** in [HLR12](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S000187081200206X/1-s2.0-S000187081200206X-main.pdf?_tid=0c58e15d-32d0-4277-ba7b-7aa02d8e693f&acdnat=1541925475_133f9de14a46d1c9cf4d29e27bf9af1c).

Comment: Smooth sliceness may be verified by a movie of knot diagrams. See e.g. Example 1.7 https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/sliceknots2.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Paolo Lisca showed that

**Theorem**([L07](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701610)): If 2-bridge knot $K$ is ribbon, then $K$ is slice.